# Joint compound over plasterboard?

Tags: drywall, plaster

I planned on drywall installation in my bedroom but accidentally bought plasterboard. I applied joint compound before realizing.  Can I salvage this by skim coating the walls? Can I sand afterwards?
Thanks

Comment: Where are you located? Can you be specific about what it is you bought?

Comment: Providing a specific brand and type from the board itself (or a picture of the label at the store or a link to their website) will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Plasterboard and drywall board are kind of the same thing. Do you mean you bought square edged boards instead of tapered edge boards?

If so, square edged boards need mesh tape over the joints (or joint tape if you've already done it) and then a two coat skimming plaster. And no, it's not normally sanded as this leaves a rough finish, not to mention a lot of dust.

Skimming plaster is designed to be finished 'from the trowel'.